# OpenCV: How to get contours of object that is black and white?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, contour

I have problems getting the contours of an object in my picture(s).

In order to delete all noise, I use `adjustROI()` and `Canny()`.

I also tried `erode()` and `dillate()`, `Laplacian()`, `GaussianBlur()`, `Sobel()`... and I even found this code snippet to sharpen a picture:

```
GaussianBlur(src, dst_gaussian, Size(0, 0), 3);

addWeighted(src, 1.5, dst_gaussian, -0.5, 0, dst);
```

But my result is always the same: My object is filled with black and white colour (like noise on a TV-screen) so that it is impossible to get the contours with `findContours()` (`findContours()` finds a million of contours, but not the one of the whole object. I check this with `drawContours()`).

I use C++ and I load my picture as a grayscale Mat (for Canny it has to be grayscale). My object has a diffenent shape on every picture, but it is always around the middle of the picture.

I either need to find a way to get a better coloured object by image processing - but I don't know what else to try - or a way how to fill the object with colour after image processing (without having it's contours, because this is what I want in the end).

Any ideas are welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will be very hard to answer if you do not provide examples . I understood from your former post that you cannot put the pictures since you do not 'own' them. Please, could you generate images that are similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works in most cases. I fill my object using the probabilistic Hough transform `HoughLinesP()`.

```
vector<Vec4i> lines;
HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 80, 30, 10);
for(size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
    line(color_dst, Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]), Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8);
}
```

This is from some sample code OpenCV documentation provides.

After using some edge-detection algorithm (like `Canny()`), the probabilistic Hough transform finds objects in binary pictures. The algorithm finds lines, which, if drawn, represent the whole object. Of course some of the parameters have to be adapted for some kind of picture.

I'm not sure if this will work on every picture or every object, but in my case, it does.